# Set theory: Every two infinite countable , well ordered sets are similar.

Tags: set-theory

Prove or find a counter example: 
Every two infinite countable , well ordered sets are similar.

There's a theorem that says that there is a unique function of similarity between two similar well ordered sets, so I guess I would have to define that function.
I tried indexing the elements of both sets from 0,1,2,.. and so on and defining the function of similarity by assigning the minimum of one set to the other and so on so that the indexes match ( where the minimum would have the index 0). I think that is a bijective function.
I can't think of a counter example.

Comment: What do you think of $\mathbb{N}$ with a point added "to infinity" ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'similar'?

Comment: What definition of "similar" are you using? For example, here are two infinite, countable, well-ordered sets $A$ and $B$, are they similar? $A = \{1,2,3,4,...\}$ with its usual ordering; and $B = A \cup \{\infty\}$ where $n < \infty$ for each $n \in \{1,2,3,4,...\}$.

Comment: That two sets are similar if there is a increasing bijective function between them.

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov $\Bbb Q_{\ge0}$ is not well-ordered, so $\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ is the go-to example

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I was mixing some definitions up. If forgot that every non-empy subset must have a least element instead of just the set itself. Thanks, I deleted my comment.